# Replace character with other character in a text file using perl

Tags: linux, perl

I am having problem in parsing the output from the text file. I want to add pipe symbol in between the character to do mutliple search similar to egrep, the text file is as follows

```
service entered the stopped state,critical
service entered the running state,clear
```

Code:

```
open(my $data, '<', $Config_File) or die "Could not open '$Config_File"
my $reg_exp;
my $severity;
my @fields=();
while (my $line = <$data>) 
{  
   chomp $line;   
   if(!$line =~ /^$/)
   {
   @fields = split "," , $line;
   $reg_exp = $fields[0];
   $severity = $fields[1]; 
   print $reg_exp;
   }
 }

 #print $fields[0];
 #last unless defined $line;

 close($data);
```

expected output

```
service entered the stopped state|service entered the running state
```

Comment: Can we see some input as well?

Comment: your code has nothing to do with the question asked; neither has the output. Please ask a real question, with real code and real input/output...

Comment: I had added the complete question, sorry missed full question while pasting

Comment: The input seems to be on two different lines. You want to concatenate them into one line? Are there other lines in the file? I.e. should *all* the lines in the file be concatenated to the line after?

Comment: @TLP yes what you posted is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not far off, you just need to actually concatenate the strings. The simplest way would be to push the `$fields[0]` to an array, and wait until the input is done to print it. I.e.:

```
my @data;
while (my $line = <$data>) {
   next if $line =~ /^$/;            # no need to chomp
   my @fields = split /,/, $line;
   push @data, $fields[0];
}
print join("|", @data), "\n";
```

I sense that you are trying to achieve something else with this code, and that this is a so-called [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).